# Recursively appending elements to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

In wanting to demonstrate the power of *Mathematica*, I wanted to show my 11-year-old son how we could validate that his sequences homework was correct. We could generate the next value in sequence in a simple expression, but when it came to repeatedly doing this (for the next 10 values), I got stuck.

We have seed list of values `{0,2,2,4}` which we called `seedlist`. The sequence is simply taking the last two numbers and adding them together to create the next number.

What I wanted to show was how we could generate an extended list for the first 10 (say) values e.g.

```
{0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68}
```

In an attempt to append the next value into the list we did the following

```
Append[seedlist, (Extract[seedlist, 3] + Extract[seedlist, 4])]
```

Now I wanted to be able to recursively append to the list. So I tried several approaches as follows:

1. Tried to use a function and the called NestList:

   ```
   rec[dat_, n_] :=
    Append[seedlist, (Extract[seedlist, n] + Extract[seedlist, n - 1])]

   NestList[rec[#, i] &, seedlist, {i, 1, 10}]
   ```

This gave me an error `"Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 3 in NestList[rec[#1,i]&,{0,2,2,4},{i,1,10}]"`

2. After a bit more digging in the documentation, I then tried a simpler version

   ```
   NestList[Append[
    Rest[#], (Extract[#, 4] + Extract[#, 4 - 1])] &, seedlist, 7]
   ```

This worked to a degree but I got presented with the following list

```
{{0, 2, 2, 4}, {2, 2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6, 10}, {4, 6, 10, 16}, {6, 10, 16, 26},
 {10, 16, 26, 42}, {16, 26, 42, 68}, {26, 42, 68, 110}}
```

This has all the answers, just not necessarily in the right places!
This is, without necessarily knowing it, what I asked for in the above of course but not what I want to achieve.

I'd be really grateful for someone to point me in the right direction and get the correct list out. I have a feeling I'm fairly close with the last attempt, but I'd appreciate a nudge to solve this correctly.

Comment: `NestList[Append[#, #[[-2]] + #[[-1]]] &, seedlist, 7]`

Comment: Or `NestList[#~Join~{#[[-2]] + #[[-1]]} &, seedlist, 7]`

Comment: and +1 for preaching MMA to the younger generation

Comment: `LinearRecurrence[{1, 1}, {0, 2}, 10]` is the built-in, by the way, or `RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + a[n - 1], a[1] == 2, 
  a[0] == 0}, a, {n, 0, 10}]`. (Much less pedagogical value to those.)

Comment: Wow! I buy a sandwich, come back and my question is answered. Thank you so much to all. So, in the two examples above, using Append or using Join, is there a preferred approach? Again many thanks

Comment: You might be interested in linked lists, too, to avoid the fact that Mathematica's `Append` function doesn't work in-place and so is quite slow: `Nest[{#[[2, 1]] + #[[1]], #} &, {2, {0}}, 10] // Flatten // Reverse`

Comment: Patrick: I love the last edit you added, but could you expand on how this is working? We have some shorthand for Part working on itself but I'm not sure I understand the last element contained in the curly braces. Thanks

Comment: @AnthonyMiller This is highly nonobvious, don't worry. We simulate a linked list as follows: the true list `{1,2,3,4}` is written as `{4, {3, {2, {1}}}}`. This is because it happens to be an efficient way for Mathematica to construct lists - much more efficient than `Append`. There is what is nearly a short book on the subject here on SE: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/30771

Comment: @Patrick Stevens Ah ha, excellent. Thanks for explaining and for pointing me to the list book! - more stuff to read...kindest again, Anthony

Comment: The methods in [Fibonacci Sequence Generator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31593/18476) could be adapted to this sequence.

Comment: @Karsten - SequenceFoldList? Might be interesting to play with? Thanks

Comment: @Kartsen 7 - Yes this seems to work well `fib[n_] := SequenceFoldList[Plus, {0, 2}, ConstantArray[0, n - 1]]; fib[10]` - Interesting. I wonder what is more performant though? I don't know what SequenceFoldList is doing under the covers?

Comment: I did a small performance benchmark for [Tribonacci numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96689/18476). `SequenceFoldList` did perform pretty well.

Answer (score 20):

What you have is what's known in some circles as a *linear recurrence*. That is, you have a sequence where the general term can be expressed as an appropriate combination of previous terms.

The simplest way of going about it, as has been previously noted, is to use either of `Nest[]`/`NestList[]`, like so:

```
NestList[Append[#, Total[Take[#, -2]]] &, {0, 2, 2, 4}, 6]
   {{0, 2, 2, 4}, {0, 2, 2, 4, 6}, {0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10}, {0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16},
    {0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26}, {0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42},
    {0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68}}
```

where `Take[list, -2]`, takes the *last* two (hence the negative sign) elements, and `Total[list]` sums the two elements up.

However, it should be said that there is a function called, appropriately enough, `LinearRecurrence[]`, that does this recursion in an efficient manner. Here is how to use it:

```
LinearRecurrence[{1, 1}, {0, 2}, 10]
   {0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68}
```

To explain the notation a bit, `LinearRecurrence[{1, 1}, {a, b}, k]` generates `k` terms, starting with the first two terms `a` and `b`, and then successively generates `a + b, a + 2 b, 2 a + 3 b, ...`. You can see this by feeding symbolic arguments:

```
LinearRecurrence[{1, 1}, {a, b}, 10]
   {a, b, a + b, a + 2 b, 2 a + 3 b, 3 a + 5 b, 5 a + 8 b, 8 a + 13 b,
    13 a + 21 b, 21 a + 34 b}
```

In fact, your sequence can be expressed in terms of the famous Fibonacci numbers, which satisfy the same recursion, but with different starting points. I'll skip the (deep!) math, but here's a demonstration:

```
Table[2 (Fibonacci[n - 3] + Fibonacci[n - 2]), {n, 9}]
   {0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68}
```

Comment: J.M. Excellent information again. I'll point out the Fibonacci bit to my son. I hadn't previously seen LinearRecurrence. I'll go play... Thanks Anthony

Comment: The fact that this is Fibonacci-derived means that there is a closed form for the solution, too. Mathematica will find it: `FindSequenceFunction[{0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68}, x] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify[#, x ∈ Integers] &`

Comment: @Patrick, yes, but I'm not too sure the kid will appreciate Binet at this stage. :)

Comment: @J.M. What do you mean?! All you have to do is diagonalise the appropriate matrix ;)

Comment: ...and that just might scare the father too. :P Baby steps...

Comment: Help!!! :-) Baby steps indeed :-) Thanks I'll look up Binet though but with one eye closed in case it's too scary. Kindest

Comment: @Anthony, well [if you insist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_formula); the neat thing about it is that it involves the famous golden ratio, and it's not immediately obvious from the formula that the results are actually integers. :) Go forth, adventurer!

Comment: ... regarding this answer and its helpful comments one might also stop by and look up the "other" [Binet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Binet). ;)

Comment: I'm confused, why not go all the way with `2 Table[Fibonacci[n - 1], {n, 9}]`? If you divide the starting numbers by 2, this is immediately clear, right?

Comment: @Jacob, you're right! I was hoping somebody would notice that you can apply the recurrence forward to the expression I gave. ;)

Comment: So I see you like a puzzle :). It is funny to see old responses that start with @Guesswhoitis by the way, now people don't even have a link to your profile to help them figure out!

Comment: @Jacob, I guess I should've gone with m_goldberg's suggestion, "You all know who it is." :)

Answer (score 11):

```
NestList[Append[#, #[[-2]] + #[[-1]]] &, {0, 2, 2, 4}, 5]
```

`[[-2]]` means the second last element; `#` instead of `Rest[#]` is used to prevent discarding of the first element. As we can count elements from the end, we don't have the problem of needing to know the length of the seed list. We might as well have done

```
NestList[Append[#, #[[-2]] + #[[-1]]] &, {0, 2}, 7]
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for giving me two answers :-)

Answer (score 10):

It can be done elegantly with tail recursion.

```
series[a_, b_, n_] := Flatten[helper[a, b, n, {}]]
helper[_, _, 0, s_] := s
helper[a_, b_, n_, s_] := helper[b, a + b, n - 1, {s, a}]

series[0, 2, 10]
```

> `{0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68}`

When the 1st two arguments are set to 1, `series` gives the Fibonacci series.

```
series[1, 1, 10] == Table[Fibonacci[i], {i, 10}]
```

> `True`

Comment: Is there is reason why you are using the undefined `term`. I tried using `List` instead and it's even faster.

Comment: @Karsten7.Habit. Most of my tail-recursive code deals with accumulating lists of some complexity. I have become habituated to using a tag when accumulating them into a linked structure to make the final flattening easier. As you point out, there is no need for that here. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use recursion. If you don't have a large number simple recursion will do, but if the sequence you are creating is big you can speed it up (at the expense of memory) by using `Set` when you define the function (a method called **memoization**).

```
func[n_] := func[n] = func[n - 1] + func[n - 2]
func[1] = 0;
func[2] = 2;
```

This function won't give you the list but rather provides you with the value.

```
func[10]
(* 68 *)
```

Now however, if you examine `func` you will see

```
?func
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All of the intermediate values have been assigned.

To create the desired list use `Map`.

```
Map[func, Range[10]]
(* {0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your sequence satisfies the following recursive formula

$a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}(n\geq 1) \quad a_0=0, a_1=2$

Trying this

```
First /@ NestList[{#2, #1 + #2} & @@ # &, {0, 2}, 9]
```

> ```
> {0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68}
> ```

For the general formula $a_{n+1}=$ `func` $(a_{n-1},a_n)$, you can use the a general solution

> `# & @@@NestList[{#2, func[#1,#2]} & @@ # &, {a1, a2}, n]`
>
> where $n$ is the $n$-th number

About the explonation, please the following post

- [Nonlinear recurrence relation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23268/nonlinear-recurrence-relation/63888#63888)

---

For recursion formula $a_{n}=\alpha a_{n-1}+\beta a_{n-2}\quad (n \geq 2)$

we can use the following strtegy.ie. *built-in* `MatrixPower[]`.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n-1}\\
a_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n-1}\\
\alpha a_{n-1}+\beta a_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
\beta & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n-2}\\
a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
=\cdots
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
\beta & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}^{n-2}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
=A^{n-2}\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where,
$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
\beta & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
$

Answer (score 1):

I like everyone's answers, but it seems to me that your first approach is most appropriate for a 11-year-old kid new to MMA. Keep it simple and leave the pure functions and exotic syntax for another day. :)

Perhaps something like this:

```
next[list_] := Append[list, list[[-1]] + list[[-2]]]
```

So that

```
next[{0, 2, 2, 4}]
```

returns

```
{0,2,2,4,6}
```

Then

```
Nest[next, {0, 2, 2, 4}, 10]
```

returns

```
{0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68, 110, 178, 288, 466}
```

After all, you're trying to show how simple and easy it is to check your homework with MMA :)